# Building a templated ASP.NET control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm playing around with a composite control that uses the ASP.NET templating system.

I want to be able to define a `HeaderTemplate` and a `FooterTemplate` in my markup, and programmatically add a `UserControl` between the two.

The markup I'm aiming for is something like this:

```html
<asp:DropZone runat="server" ID="LeftZone">
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <h1>Getting started</h1>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
      <h3>The end of it...</h3>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DropZone>
```

My DropZone class looks like this:

```
public class DropZone : Control, INamingContainer
{
    private ITemplate headerTemplate;
    private ITemplate footerTemplate;

   [DefaultValue((string)null), 
    Browsable(false), 
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), 
    TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
    public virtual ITemplate HeaderTemplate
    {
        get { return headerTemplate; }
        set { headerTemplate = value; }
    }

   [DefaultValue((string)null), 
    Browsable(false), 
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), 
    TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
    public ITemplate FooterTemplate
    {
        get { return footerTemplate; }
        set { footerTemplate = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private void AppendTemplate(ITemplate template, Control container)
    {
        if (template == null) return;

        var ph = new PlaceHolder();
        container.Controls.Add(ph);
        template.InstantiateIn(ph);
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Clear();

        AppendTemplate(HeaderTemplate, this);

        Control helloWorld = Page.LoadControl("~/WebParts/HelloWorld.ascx");
        if (helloWorld != null)
        {
            Controls.Add(helloWorld);
        }

        AppendTemplate(FooterTemplate, this);

        ChildControlsCreated = true;
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
}
```

However, this does not work as the `ITemplate` fields are never instantiated.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I had to derive my custom control from `CompositeControl` to get things work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See (for instance) [Templated Server Control Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178657.aspx), and [MSDN Search for "asp.net templated controls"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?query=asp.net%20templated%20controls&refinement=27&ac=1).

Comment: Thank you. Apparently I have to derive my DropZone control from CompositeControl instead of just Control - now everything works as expected.

Comment: Ah, yes. CompositeControl is your friend.

Comment: You can also just implement INamingContainer instead of composite control. It is a marker template to ensure unique ids are outputted. CompositeControl does this which is why it works.